# How to stop reloading the google map when the state is changes in React?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, google-maps

I have a React app and I have a Google Map Component.

This one:

```
    <GoogleMap
      center={center}
      zoom={3}
      onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
      mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    >
       
       {data.toDisplayOnMap.length > 0 && (
          <>
           {data.toDisplayOnMap.map((element, i) => {

             if ('events' in element.item) {
                return <Marker key={i} position={element.item.locationCoords} onClick={() => navigate(`/location?id=${element.id}`)} icon={`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png`} />
             } else if ('waypoints' in element.item) {

              if (element.item.traveltype === 'location') {

              return <DirectionsRenderer options={{ preserveViewport: true, polylineOptions: { strokeColor: 'blue', strokeWeight: 2 }, markerOptions: { icon: `http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png` } }} directions={element.route} />
               } else {
                    let wps = element.item.waypoints;;
                    let coords = [];
                    wps.forEach((wp) => {
                        wp.coords.forEach((coord) => {
                             coords.push(coord)
                                                        })
                    })

                                                    
                  return (<>
                   <Marker position={coords[0]} icon={`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png`} />
                   <Marker position={coords[coords.length - 1]} icon={`http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png`} />
               <Polyline path={coords} options={{ geodesic: true, strokeColor: '#000', strokeOpacity: 1, strokeWeight: 2, editable: false, draggable: false, clickable: true }} />
                   </>)
                }
             }
          })}
        </>
   )}


    </GoogleMap>
```

Well what is happening is I have a list of objects and if people are checking a Checkbox it is displayed on the map, but my center is in Africa and a zoom of 3 so I can get the most of the map. If I zoom in to see that Marker or that PolyLine and then I deselect the checkbox, it reloads the map and move me back to Africa. I don't really know how can I use this with a useMemo or something like that because What is displayed on my map it's coming from the state of the page. I tried useMemo, but probably I used it wrong because it was doing nothing. And also in my console I have this

```
253 useJsApiLoader.tsx:62 Performance warning! LoadScript has been reloaded unintentionally!
```

This is how I declared my map:
 `const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */(null))`

```
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        googleMapsApiKey: ct.MAPS_API_KEY,
        libraries: p
    })
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces this issue? A working codesanbox link would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use react hook useMemo to prevent re-rendering of components. You can use useMemo this way

```
const renderGoogleMap = useMemo(() => {
  return <GoogleMap {...props} />;
}, []);
```

and call this memoize function as

```
<div>
  {renderGoogleMap}
</div>
```

you can also pass deps to useMemo hook on change of that deps you can allow to re-render the view.